# Unused parameters when using an interface

Tags: python, user-interface

I'm creating a GUI for a project of mine using Python. Even though this is a private project, I would like to use good coding practices. First, let me introduce a simplified version of my GUI module:

```
# Just a box, can have borders or it can be filled
class Box(object):
    def __init__(self):
        # Set initial state

    def update(self, xy, press):
        # I'm just a dummy box, I don't care about xy or press
        pass

    def draw(self):
        # Draw

# Like a box but with special functionality
class Button(Box):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Button, self).__init__()
        # Set initial state

    def update(self, xy, press):
        # Do something with xy and press

# Like a box but with special functionality
class Status(Box):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Status, self).__init__()
        # Set initial state

    def update(self, xy, press):
        # Do something with xy, ignore press

# A box which can hold boxes inside it to group them
class Container(Box):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Container, self).__init__()
        self.childs = deque()

    def update(self, xy, press):
        for c in self.childs:
             c.update(xy, press)

    # Container draws itself like a Box but also draws boxes inside it
    def draw(self):
        super(Container, self).draw()
        for c in self.childs:
                c.draw()
```

Every GUI component is in a *container*. *Container's* update() gets called every cycle to update the state of those components with the latest input information.

I like this solution since it allows me to use an interface to update the whole GUI in one loop and it saves a bit of code. My problem is that some of these childs need more information than others to update their state which leads into unused parameters with the use of the interface.

So, is the use of unused parameters considered a bad practice in this case and should I just give up using the interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way to do this is called cooperative inheritance, which is essentially just a buzzword to say that both the super- and the sub- class expect each other to be around and be passed information it may not need. Methods of this type tend to look like:

```
def foo(self, specific, arguments, *args, **kwargs):
    do_something_with(specific, arguments)
    super(MyClass, self).foo(*args, **kwargs)
```

in other words, each more-specific `Container` handles what's special about it, but if there's default functionality that's common to all `Container`s (and if there isn't -- why are we using inheritance?!) then you define that only in the superclass and use `super` to defer to it in the subclass.